# Cast array to object

Tags: f#

I have an array and I want to cast it to an object. This is my code.

```
let a = [| 1 |]
let b = a :?> obj
```

but it tells me that `int [] has no proper subtypes and cannot be used as a source of runtime type coercion`. I'm pretty sure I can always do `(object)` in C# without the compiler complaining, so what's the issue here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to downcast (`:?>`), instead of upcast (`:>`). Your code should be:

```
let a = [| 1 |]
let b = a :> obj
```

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx for more details.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I have no idea why that didn't occur to me. I've even explicitly dismissed the idea...

Answer (score 8):

While ebb's answer is of course correct, there is another solution for the special case of upcasting to `obj`, which is the `box` operator:

```
let a = [| 1 |]
let b = box a
```

In F#, `box` doesn't have the same meaning as it does in the CLR, where it means "make a reference-type object corresponding to a value-type value."  In F#, it just means "cast to `obj`."  Because of this, you can use `box` with reference types as well as with value types.